# How to get spacing between an image and my form?

Tags: html

Below I have some code.  I am trying to put spacing between an image  and  a form.  As you can see below I have used 3 brake tags but they don't work here.  Any advice?

```
<img height="150" width="200" src = "images/images/computer1.jpg" alt="Computer Support"/>
<br/><br/><br/>

<form method = "post" action = "mailto:info@ncirl.ie">

<fieldset>


<legend>Please Register Your Details</legend>
```

Comment: Works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/yKHRq/

Comment: I put it in a fiddle and the line breaks are working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/pPsgL/ Are you also seeing this? You could you use `margin-top: 30px;` as well to get space instead of using `<br/>`

Comment: I think it will depend more on the front-end framework and its css that you are using. On basic HTML page, it works fine as @DSG link shows

Comment: No none of those work either

Answer (score 1):

Well since i got no answer that could me  with this .  I can only assume that the only reason my brake tags wern't working here was because i had the images in a seperate float and column to the other images, where the brake tags all work fine. I am fully aware of putting the top of bottom margin at a certain measure in CSS eg "margin-top: 30px" of margin-bottom: 30px". but i didnt want to use it here beacuse all the images on my site will move and i dont want to do this. So the only solution i could find to this problem was in line styling which i dont like doing but it works fine there.  Which i knew it would.
I just stil cant figure out why in this situation my brake tags had no effect whatsoever.

Comment: that could be it. You do know that you could add an ID to the image, apply your styling, and then not change your other images